# Is there an IEEE recognized method for splicing Category 5e or 6 cabling?

Tags: layer1, cable, cabling, utp

Is there an IEEE recognized method for splicing Category 5e or 6 cabling, and maintaining the expected data rates?

Such as the junction box shown in the link below.

https://www.lowvoltagecables.com/keystone-jack-inserts/junction-box.html

Comment: The answer is absolutely correct.  Whenever you cut an Ethernet cable, put on a connector.  Even if that means picking up a small 4-port Cisco switch to go in between them.  They are available from the usual sources for very low prices.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

Copper cable splices are not allowed. Cabling standards are set by *ANSI/TIA/EIA 568 Commercial Building Telecommunications Cabling Standard*. For instance, this is for copper cabling:

> Only one transition point or consolidation point between the
>   horizontal cross connect and the telecommunications outlet shall be
>   allowed, and bridged taps and splices are not allowed in the copper
>   horizontal.

You are allowed to splice fiber cabling, but you must consider the effect on your link attenuation and loss budget.

Also, simply using parts that are rated at a category doesn't necessarily mean that you end up with a rated link. Installation is the biggest failure in cabling. You must use a proper tester (quite expensive, but can normally be rented, if you know what you are doing) to run the link through the test suite for the particular category. Any failures must be fixed. Even experienced installers can have trouble getting Category 6 or 6a to pass the test suite. You can permanently ruin a cable by exceeding the minimum bend radius or maximum pulling tension when installing, and I have seen simple things like having the Blue wire on top of the Blue/White at the termination prevent the link from passing the test suite.

Comment: Thank You Ron, I work for a large aluminum mill and the contractor was going to use a "splice panel" to extend the cables in our offices. I questioned them about this method. I am an electrician who has pulled and terminated probably over one thousand Cat5/6 cables and thought this was a bad idea. Thanks again for your expert advise.